# How do I disable rotation in Mapbox Android SDK

Tags: android, mapbox

I want to disable rotation (bearing) in Mapbox Android SDK because it is currently too sensitive - when I pinched to zoom, the map also rotate.

I tried adding these attributes to the layout:

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    ...
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraBearing="0.0"
    mapbox:mapbox_uiCompass="false"
    ... >
</com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>
```

But learnt later that they are used for setting the initial rotation and hiding the compass respectively.

How do I disable the rotation in Mapbox Android SDK?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**`public void setRotateGesturesEnabled(boolean rotateGesturesEnabled)`**](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.0.1/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/UiSettings.html#setRotateGesturesEnabled-boolean-)

> Changes whether the user may rotate the map.
>
> This setting controls only user interactions with the map. If you set
>   the value to false, you may still change the map location
>   programmatically.

```
getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 7):

Solved with the following code! Thanks for the hint.

```
...
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
    }
});
...
```